# In vb.net, how do you force-exit an application and stifle error messages?

Tags: exception, objectdisposedexception

I want the user to simply be able to exit my application. However, for some reason, code which I have on a time delay, controlled by a stopwatch, is still trying to execute. I do not care if it tries to do so or not, but I want to stop the error and force-quit the application, terminating ALL running threads where they stand.

I am using Visual Basic Express 2008 with SP1, and I am coding in vb.net, this is a WinForm application.

I have tried simply closing the forms with **Formname.Close()** and I also tried **Application.Exit()**. I even tried an If Then statement which exited the thread which referenced my textbox, quitting it with **Application.ExitThread()**

I got:

ObjectDisposedException was unhandled

Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'TextBox'.

How can I handle this exception or simply finish exiting?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: To clarify, I don't care how this is achieved, I just want the application to stop running, and have no errors occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you shut off the stopwatch before you exit?

Comment: The stopwatch is declared from within a subroutine, it had already stopped by the time the ObjectDisposedException occurred.

Comment: There may be something else going on.  Try deleting your text box and/or your stopwatch and see if it exits w/o error.  Try to isolate which object/condition is causing the problem.

Comment: It is still executing the code "LoadBox.AppendText(LoadProgress.Text + Environment.NewLine)" when it has already executed. How do I stop this?

Comment: Eh, I solved my problem. I simply removed the ability to quit the application at that point in time. It was a two-second process anyway, if they can't be patient for that then that stinks for them ;).

Comment: glad you fixed it.  sometimes the problem is simply that you're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

The worst case scenario solution to your problem is:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess.Kill()
```

Regards,
Zibri